# How to declare integer values as constants using enum class?

Tags: java, enums

I have a set of integer values which I need to define as a part of enum, I'm doing this.

```
public enum Test{

    763("763"),
    1711("1711"),
    8050("8050"),
    9311("9311");

    private Integer test;

    Test(Integer test) {
        this.test= test;
    }

    public Integer getTest() {
        return test;
    }

}
```

It gives me unexpected token on the first line.. What is missing here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Rule #1: All variable names must begin with a letter of the alphabet, an underscore, or (_), or a dollar sign ($). The convention is to always use a letter of the alphabet. The dollar sign and the underscore are discouraged.

You defined a constructor passing an Integer Object but in the Enum list you passed a String Object.

Comment: @mashkum why do you want to do that?

Comment: Why exactly do you want to have enum constants with a name that is a number – what is the business context here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java does not allow variables to start with a number. Take a look at the [official variable rules](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html). Furthermore, you should pass `test` as an integer and not as a `String`.

A working solution might look like the following:

```
public enum Test {
  T_763(763),
  T_1711(1711),
  T_8050(8050),
  T_9311(9311);

  private Integer test;

  Test(Integer test) {
    this.test = test;
  }

  public Integer getTest() {
    return test;
  }

}
```

Comment: The underscore is bad style, though. It should be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

1. Typo with opening curly brace in constructor
2. Enumerations themselves can't be numbers (these are names that can't be numbers in java)
3. The value is declared integer but you pass String.

Here is a fixed version of what you're trying to do:

```
public enum Test {
    T_763(763),
    T_1711(1711),
    T_8050(8050),
    T_9311(9311);

    private final Integer test;
    Test(Integer test) {
        this.test= test;
    };
    public Integer getTest() {
        return test;
    }

}
```